# Understanding the "Why" of a file access code snippet

Tags: go, winapi, file-permissions, logical-operators, file-access

I have been trying to make sense of a code snippet for past some days. You can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/pkrnjevic/7219861)

**Overview**

The code reads MFT of a Windows drive, creates a struct of maps of files in the MFT. Then it goes on reading the USN Journal to detect what has changed of those files.

**Problem**

There are some logical operations happening in the script. I can understand what the code part is doing but why is it doing so is what has been haunting me for past couple of days. I stumbled upon various Windows docs like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-security-and-access-rights) but even then, it did not make much sense to me.

For example -

```
switch mode & (O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_RDWR) {
case O_RDONLY:
    access = GENERIC_READ
case O_WRONLY:
    access = GENERIC_WRITE
case O_RDWR:
    access = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
}
if mode&O_CREAT != 0 {
    access |= GENERIC_WRITE
}
if mode&O_APPEND != 0 {
    access &^= GENERIC_WRITE
    access |= FILE_APPEND_DATA
}
```

Why are we doing these logical operations? There are other instances of such parts in the code also. If anyone can point me to the direction or help me why these operations are done, it'd be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you direct me to a resource where I can find these? And why do we do these? @AlexF

Comment: Anything else that you can suggest me to look into before I can venture deep in this area? And thanks for the quick replies @AlexF

Comment: Unclear, what you are having difficulty with. If you understand bits and how to filter out, set, unset, or toggle bits, you can easily answer the question for yourself.

Comment: @IInspectable the difficulty I am having here is understanding WHY are we doing these operations. I have written in the question as well that I can not understand WHY are we doing logical operations because I can't find a resource that I can refer to, to make sense as "Ah! this is why we have bitwise AND and XOR", I hope that clears what I am having difficulty with?

Comment: I don't know about Go specifically, but there is a terminology problem here: These are definitely bitwise not logical operations. Logical operators result in a boolean and perform whatever language defined translation is in place to ensure their inputs are converted to boolean values. bitwise operators assume the operands have equal storage size, and perform the logical operation for each pair of bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a conversion from the Linux (POSIX) API `open` (`man 2 open`; http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to the Windows API `CreateFile` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew).

---

For the original code, see `src/syscall/syscall_windows.go` (https://go.googlesource.com/go):

```
func Open(path string, mode int, perm uint32) (fd Handle, err error) {
    if len(path) == 0 {
        return InvalidHandle, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    }
    pathp, err := UTF16PtrFromString(path)
    if err != nil {
        return InvalidHandle, err
    }
    var access uint32
    switch mode & (O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_RDWR) {
    case O_RDONLY:
        access = GENERIC_READ
    case O_WRONLY:
        access = GENERIC_WRITE
    case O_RDWR:
        access = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
    }
    if mode&O_CREAT != 0 {
        access |= GENERIC_WRITE
    }
    if mode&O_APPEND != 0 {
        access &^= GENERIC_WRITE
        access |= FILE_APPEND_DATA
    }
    sharemode := uint32(FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE)
    var sa *SecurityAttributes
    if mode&O_CLOEXEC == 0 {
        sa = makeInheritSa()
    }
    var createmode uint32
    switch {
    case mode&(O_CREAT|O_EXCL) == (O_CREAT | O_EXCL):
        createmode = CREATE_NEW
    case mode&(O_CREAT|O_TRUNC) == (O_CREAT | O_TRUNC):
        createmode = CREATE_ALWAYS
    case mode&O_CREAT == O_CREAT:
        createmode = OPEN_ALWAYS
    case mode&O_TRUNC == O_TRUNC:
        createmode = TRUNCATE_EXISTING
    default:
        createmode = OPEN_EXISTING
    }
    h, e := CreateFile(pathp, access, sharemode, sa, createmode, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
    return h, e
}
```